# Running app on iPad simulator 12.9inch and 9.7inch cut some views

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am testing and configuring my application for iOS devices. On iPad Simulators 12.9 inch and 9.7 inch, some views are not showing properly. I am using different storyboard for different devices and not using autoLayout. If I run on actual device, there is no issue.

[image]

Comment: Did u try scrolling the simulator screen if you're not using it on full screen?  Did you try Cmd+1 /2 /3 /4 ??

Comment: No scrolling and I am using full screen. This issue was also in my old version but at that time I ignored because everything works ok on actual device. Now I thought to post it because it is weird.

Comment: okays. Let see if someone has answer for this.

Comment: Try to reset your simulator and check.

Comment: After resetting, issue remains.

Comment: I am facing same issue with autolayout.

Comment: Just delete your old segues and create new one. It will be solved. Use push segue or default. Do not use custom segues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com and attach your project along with screenshots of what it should look like and what it actually looks like?

I have found that if UI is broken in the Simulator it is a sign there is something wrong and sooner or later it will show up broken on device too. It might be an OS update, or a different orientation, or maybe just losing a race condition... but sooner or later the problem bites you.

Comment: Okay, I will report